# Audio Discord Bot Play/Pause

Tags: javascript, audio, discord.js, bots

Hey I'm working with this bot that's open-source It's the most responsive bot for messing with my friends and uses Discord.js

The issue I have is when the bot detects voice it starts the audio file from the beginning. I want it to pause then resume the file unless its reached the end. Unfortunately I am not familiar with discord.js

If anyone can give me a hand that would be fantastic!

```js
const fs = require('fs'),
{ Client, } = require('discord.js')

const { token, bypass } = require('./config.json')
const client = new Client()

let previousChannel, connection, dispather;
client
.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})
.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
    if (newState.id == client.user.id) return
    if (newState.channelID !== null) previousChannel = newState.channelID
    if (newState.channelID == null && !bypass.includes(newState.id) && !!previousChannel) {
        client.channels.cache.get(previousChannel).leave()
        return [previousChannel, dispather] = [null, null];
    }

    if (bypass.includes(newState.id)) return
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get(newState.channelID)
    if (!channel) return

    return connection = await channel.join()
})
.on('guildMemberSpeaking', async (member, speaking) => {
    if (!connection) return
    if (bypass.includes(member.user.id)) return

    if (!dispather)
        dispather = connection.play(fs.createReadStream('./audio.mp3'), {
            volume: 1
        })
    else if (dispather && !speaking.bitfield) {
        dispather.destroy()
        dispather = undefined
    }
})
.on('error', console.log)
.on('warn', console.log)
.login(token)

process.on('unhandledRejection', console.log)
```

Comment: This "I want it to pause then resume the file unless its reached the end" is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`StreamDispatcher`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=pause)'s `.resume()` and `.pause()` methods.

```js
if (speaking.bitfield) {
    dispather.resume();
} else {
    dispather.pause();
}
```

If you are using Node.js v14.17.0+ there may be some [weird bugs](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/5300) occurring.

> I also found this happening for LTS v14.17.0
> Fixed by using v14.16

Also you might find helpful Discord.js's [new Voice API implementation](https://github.com/discordjs/voice) they are working on.

> We're working on a new implementation of Discord's Voice API that has better playback quality and is more reliable than what we currently support in Discord.js v12.
> The new library solves many of the issues that users are facing, and as part of this, we're dropping built-in support for voice in our next major release.